# .htaccess error after change server

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have changed my hosting and get a 404 error on one website where we have using .htaccess file and code like this, now what happening sub-cat page showing 404 error http://www.natural-stones-india.com/sandstone/Golden%20Brown%20Black.html

.htaccess code is like this ----------- can anyone help?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  ^sandstone/(.*).html$  product.php?sandstone=$1
RewriteRule  ^slate/(.*).html$  product.php?slate=$1
RewriteRule  ^marble/(.*).html$ product.php?marble=$1
RewriteRule  ^granite/(.*).html$    product.php?granite=$1
RewriteRule  ^artifacts/(.*).html$  product.php?artifacts=$1

RewriteRule  ^page/(.*)/sandstone/(.*).html$    product.php?page=$1&sandstone=$2
RewriteRule  ^page/(.*)/granite/(.*).html$  product.php?page=$1&granite=$2
RewriteRule  ^page/(.*)/marble/(.*).html$   product.php?page=$1&marble=$2
RewriteRule  ^page/(.*)/artifacts/(.*).html$    product.php?page=$1&artifacts=$2
RewriteRule  ^page/(.*)/slate/(.*).html$    product.php?page=$1&slate=$2

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [nc]

RewriteRule  ^action/(.*)/id/(.*)/cat/(.*)/sub_cat/(.*)shoppingcart.html$   shoppingcart.php?action=$1&id=$2&cat=$3&sub_cat=$4
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^natural-stones-india.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.natural-stones-india.com/$1 [R=301,L]

<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
```

Comment: Can you go directly to `product.php?sandstone=$1` in the browser? (Passing relevant values for `$1` of course.)

Answer (score 1):

OK, let's analyze some facts

- Webserver does not respond with 500 Internal server error)

  Conclusion: Your .htaccess file seems to be syntactically correct
- Webserver does some of the rewrites correctly, also the custom error document is working

  Conclusion: Your .htaccess file is actually read by the webserver
- By the first look all rewrites based in the document root seem to work
  http://www.natural-stones-india.com/granite.html works, while http://www.natural-stones-india.com/granite/Pink%20Granite.html does not

Conclusion: You have a problem with relative paths

**Possible solution:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
...
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteBase

Or set the rewrite targets absolute

e.g.

```
RewriteRule  ^sandstone/(.*).html$  /product.php?sandstone=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your access rights to the .htaccess file
You should be able to change these through FTP.

You site seems fine, since this i working: http://www.natural-stones-india.com/product.php?sandstone=Golden%20Brown%20Black